# ios dynamic constraint property for self sizing cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I have been using constraint for self-sizing and for this case, I don't know how to set up. [image]

If the time label 15-7-2016 maximum y position is higher than imageview, I want that label to determine cell height. If it is not higher, I just want to keep offset of imageview.

What do I need to set up or change programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below constraints

1. ImageView: top, leading, trailing, and bottom @750(high priority)
2. First Label: Top , bottom, leading, trailing
3. Second Label: Top, leading, trailing, bottom (>= 20)

Hope this will help.

[image]

Comment: I need bottom margin of label 2 to be 20 only when maximum y position of that label 2 is more than imageview. According to yours, it will always be 83.5 when label 2 height is may be at about 200.

Comment: You can set the bottom constraint of label2 to >=20, in sample code I didn't charge it

Answer (score 1):

[image]Add the following constraints:

1. For the ImageView - Top,Leading,a constant
   width and height
2. For the Top Label - Align top to the ImageView,Align Leading to the
   label
3. For the Second Label(which has dynamic Height) - Align Leading to
   the top Label,Top Space to top Label,Trailing to the superview and
   bottom space to superview.Set the number of lines to 0. Also decrease the content hugging
   priority - Vertical of this label to 250.

In the view did load, set myTableView.estimatedRowHeight property to the custom cell row height that you have provided in the storyboard file.

Comment: I have tried. it is not working because bottom space to superview (from second label) is 59 and it always take that value. I need it to be 20 when maximum y position of second label is more than imageview.  How shall I do?

Comment: Also, what shall I do if I need first label height to be dynamic?

Comment: could you share a screenshot of the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: i have edited my answer and provided a screenshot of the result that i get.
I hope you needed this functionality.

Comment: thanks. your solution seem to be working in yr screenshot. could you also do for title to be dynamic ? And can u also make image view height higher so that your second label bottom offset need to be dynamic (currently, your one is at about 20)?

Comment: Thanks. you have shown the possible way. upvote for your answer.